# iPhone App submission and removing a binary

Tags: iphone, binary, app-store

I've submitted my application to the app store and had it approved. I'd set the release date to a few months in the future, but in the meantime have added a lot of extra functionality to the product.

I still want my app to be listed as a 'new release' when it comes out (the release data hasn't been reached yet) so should I replace the binary, or do I have to remove the old app completely and start a new app?

Obviously, the previously approved app hasn't been released so I don't want the new code to be counted as an update.

Cheers,

Bryn

Comment: This is a question about the functioning of iTunes Connect, and is not programming related.  I'd suggest asking at Apple's developer forums instead: https://devforums.apple.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question here mainly because there is much more active iPhone community here, coupled with the huge amount of questions regarding iStore submission/code signing etc.

For anyone still wanting an answer to this:

If the application has not ever been released, reject the binary and create a new application altogether. If you want to keep the same name as the app you'll have problems since Apple won't allow you to completely remove the old application and you can't have two with the same name. In this case, email them directly explaining the situation and they should rename the old application to an arbitrary name, freeing up the name for the new app